# How to inject partial pages with data in Angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have Dashboard Page.
It has two columns 
One on the left and other on the right side.
Left Div contains Links [Home,Profile] 
When user clicks on the link on the left side, "Right DIV" data changes accordingly.
**What I have tried** 
I used Angular directive **ng-switch** in order to load partials in page.

```
<div class="col-lg-2">
      <h3>MENU</h3>
      <a href="#" ng-model="RESOURCES" ng-click="page='resources'">Resources</a>
      <br>
      <a href="#" ng-click="page='users'">Users</a>

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-10 card">

      <div ng-switch on="page">
        <div ng-switch-when="resources">
        <h3>Dashboard</h3>
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-when="users">
          <h3>Users</h3>
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-default>
          <h4>Default</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

But now I want to inject partial page with data coming from database.
How can I achieve that.
Please Help.

Comment: ng-switch won't allow you to `resolve` into new views, are you looking for a [tabs](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#tabs) instead ?

Comment: you may need to use ui-router instead

Comment: @svarog : will that allow me to call webservice and display data inot different view , but on the same page. ?

Comment: `select() $ - An optional expression called when tab is activated. Supports $event in template for expression`, that will fire an event when you change a tab, use that to run a function that will do the calling. for larges, similar use cases use a router like Rahul said

Comment: @svarog : If I will use ui-router, then I have to modify my all ng-routes

Comment: it seems that your requirement will be fixed by
<div ng-include="'partial.htm'"></div>

Comment: @MohammadRezaRahimi :Okay , using ng-include, can I inject one HTML page that will have data.?

Comment: are your partial  files dynamic or static?
if are dynamic you can insert data in server side .

Comment: @MohammadRezaRahimi  My partials are dynamic files, either they will contain data fetched from database or, they will be used to interact with database, like [edit.post] operations .

Comment: Also I have tried ng-imclude directive, I  could inject the partial, but I could not perform operations like [edit,post] data .

Comment: if you use rest api you must set controller for ng-include element and call rest api by $http service in controller.
<div ng-include="'partial.htm'" ng-controller="ctrl"></div>